# for loop javascript inside if statement

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to do !radios[0].checked && !radios[1].checked && !radios[2].checked in a loop and in the sometime keep the if condition as is?
my code is :

```js
    function afterLogin(event){
        event.preventDefault(); 
        if((!radios[0].checked && !radios[1].checked && !radios[2].checked) || userName.value === "" || numOfQuestions.value === ""){
            skillMsg.innerHTML = "Please check one of the skills before login";
            isTrue = false;
        }else{
            title[0].innerHTML = "Welcome " + userName.value;
            loginForm.style.display = "none";
            calForm.style.display = "block";
            formsColor.style.backgroundColor  = color.value;
            startTheGame();
            isTrue = true;
        }
        
    }
```

and this what I tried to do :

```js
    function afterLogin(event){
        event.preventDefault(); 
        for(let i = 0; i < radios.length; i++){
            if(!radios[i].checked || userName.value === "" || numOfQuestions.value === ""){
                //change the plase here
                skillMsg.innerHTML = "Please check one of the skills before login";
                return false;
            }else{
                title[0].innerHTML = "Welcome " + userName.value;
                loginForm.style.display = "none";
                calForm.style.display = "block";
                formsColor.style.backgroundColor  = color.value;
                //return true;
                startTheGame();
                //return true;
                
            }
        
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you try `radios.every(radio => !radio.checked)` ?

Comment: Hi, it doesn work with this let radios      = document.querySelectorAll("[type=radio]");

Answer (score 2):

Try this ? You can use the `Array.every` method available. For reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

```
function afterLogin(event){
    event.preventDefault(); 
    if((!radios.every(radio => radio.checked) || userName.value === "" || numOfQuestions.value === ""){
        skillMsg.innerHTML = "Please check one of the skills before login";
        isTrue = false;
    }else{
        title[0].innerHTML = "Welcome " + userName.value;
        loginForm.style.display = "none";
        calForm.style.display = "block";
        formsColor.style.backgroundColor  = color.value;
        startTheGame();
        isTrue = true;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work with let radios      = document.querySelectorAll("[type=radio]");

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible, create a different validate function to do the sanity check,
or do it in the same function itself

```
    function afterLogin(event){
        event.preventDefault(); 

        let notChecked = false;
        for(let i = 0; i < radios.length; i++){
            if(!radios[i].checked){
                notChecked = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(notChecked || userName.value === "" || numOfQuestions.value === ""){
            skillMsg.innerHTML = "Please check one of the skills before login";
            isTrue = false;
        }else{
            title[0].innerHTML = "Welcome " + userName.value;
            loginForm.style.display = "none";
            calForm.style.display = "block";
            formsColor.style.backgroundColor  = color.value;
            startTheGame();
            isTrue = true;
        }  
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't work with let radios = document.querySelectorAll("[type=radio]");

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use every() function to check this.

```
var radios = [{checked: false}, {checked: false}, {checked: false}, {checked: false}];
if(radios.every(checkValue) || userName.value === "" || numOfQuestions.value === "") {
// your code
}

function checkValue({checked}) {
  return checked === false;
}
```

Also try to use clean code principles. Like try using Fail first approach, use if and return so that you don't have to use else block there. Simply put the else part outside of if block.